# Substract two data.frames in R, by characters

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data set of 250000+ rows.

Three columns: country, test and test_result (character, character, numerical)

The next line off code reduce my data to 102388 rows.

```
sub.df1 <- df <- df[!duplicated(df), ]
```

This line off code reduce my data to 102339 rows.

```
sub.df2 <- unique(df[,c('country','test')])
```

Now i want to see these 49 rows. These rows containing the same country and test but have a different test_result.(in sub.df1)

I was trying to substract the sub.df1[1:2] - sub.df2 = sub.df3
Here sub.df2 are the 49 combinations of country and test who are appearing more then once in sub.df1.

Also tried some other approaches to reach my goal; merge(), match(), table(), rle(), but none of them sounds to fit on my problem.

Kind regards,
Brecht

Comment: Can you provide a MWE, i.e. a small piece of R code with some example data and the output you want to get? 5-10 rows will suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get the difference, you can use `duplicated`.

```
df[duplicated(df[, c('country', 'test')]), ]
```

If you want to get all the duplicates as well, you could use e.g. `data.table`.

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)
setkeyv(df, c('country', 'test'))
df[df[duplicated(df[, list(country, test)]), list(country, test)], ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, sub.df1[duplicated(sub.df1[, c('country', 'test')]), ], worked. Now i want do substract this 49 country and test combinations off the sub.df2. Is this possible, cause they are characters?

Comment: sub.df5 <- sub.df3[sub.df3$country!=sub.df4$country & sub.df3$test!=sub.df4$test, ], something like this?